# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Tags: jquery

The type is set as 'submit' but it is still not working. I'm using  `console.log` but that doesn't display anything. I'd like the console log to display a number (two added together via ajax)

How can I solve this?

**Jquery code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#formsubmit').submit(function(){
  $.post(
  PT_Ajax.ajaxurl,
        {
       action : 'ajax-inputtitleSubmit',
       noofwelds : $('input[name=numberofwelds]').val(),
       noofconwelds : $('input[name=numberofconwelds]').val(),
       nextNonce : PT_Ajax.nextNonce
        },
  function( response ) {
     console.log( response );
        }
        );
      return false;
}); 

});
})(jQuery);
});
```

**Form**

```
<form action="" method="post" type="submit" name="formsubmit" id="formsubmit"   >
<h1> Process </h1>
<p> operation type always robot </p>
<br> <br>
Number of welds: <input type="number" name="numberofwelds" id="numberofwelds"  >
<br> <br>
Number of construction welds: <input type="number" name="numberofconwelds" id="numberofconwelds"  >
<br> <br>
Total one: <input type="text" name="totalone" id="totalone" disabled>
<div id="totalfail1"></div>
<br> <br> 
Total two: <input type="text" name="totaltwo" id="totaltwo" disabled>
<div id="totalfail2"></div>
<br> <br> <br> <br>
Total three: <input type="text" name="totalthree" id="totalthree" disabled>
<div id="totalfail3"></div>
<br> <br> <br> <br>
<input type="submit"  value="Calculate" id="formsubmit" name="submit" class="ajax-link" >
<div id="result"> </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is because you have an `input` element with name `submit` in your form, rename it

```
<input type="submit"  value="Calculate" id="formsubmit" name="formsubmit" class="ajax-link" >
```

Comment: +1 Yes well seen - https://api.jquery.com/submit/ (.Submit can only be applied to form elements.. not buttons).. you have 2 elements with that ID.. ID's should be unique.

Comment: It also won't work if you have `id="submit"` on your submit button.

Comment: Thanks @Staysee! Also, do not use name="submit".