# form submit not working after validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to call a function once validation Engine returns true,then submit the form.

```
$(function() {
        $('#car_select_form').validationEngine('attach', {
            onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
                if (status == true) {                   
                    $('.clicktosubmit').trigger('click');
                    return false;
                }
            }           
        });

         $("#proceedtosave").click(function(){
            $('#car_select_form').trigger('onsubmit');
            return true;
        });
        $("#goback").click(function(){
            $('#closemyPopup').trigger('click');
        });
    });
```

Now when i try to submit using **proceedtosave** button,nothing happens.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('#car_select_form').trigger('submit');/$('#car_select_form').submit();` i guess this should have to be there.

Comment: @Jai tried that already.didn't work

Comment: @MeghaPaul hi can you provide html and JSFIDDLe..? that will batter to help you

Answer (score 0):

Do `return:true` to enable submitting.

You need to read the **[docs](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/)**.

**onValidationComplete**

When defined, it stops by default the form from auto-submitting, and lets you handle the validation status via a function. You can also return true in this function and the form will be allowed to submit.

```
jQuery("#formID2").validationEngine('attach', {
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
      alert("The form status is: " +status+", it will never submit");
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in [Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478182/uncaught-typeerror-property-submit-of-object-htmlformelement-is-not-a-func)

Make sure that there is no name="submit" or id="submit" in the form.